# How to install vcredist_x86.exe during .NET deployment setup

Tags: .net, deployment, installation

I'm trying to install the "VC++ Redistributable 9.0" during my deployment but it always failed. The problem is that this exe (vcredist_x86.exe) is also an installation process and windows does not support nested installation (or I don't know how to make it support it). I'm using a .NET setup project with C#. There is no programming. So far, I just put the .exe file in the Install custom action but when the installation runs, it fail telling me this:

**There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program rus as part of the setup did not finish as expected.**

My question is what can I do to make this work? I need this setup done ASAP or like Jack Bauer would say: NOW!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the redistributable as a pre-requisite to your setup project. This can be done under *Project -> Properties...* by clicking on the *Pre-requisites* button.

The list shown should normally include *VC++ Redistributable 9.0*.

When installing, it is important to choose the generated setup.exe file and not the .msi file. Setup.exe is a so-called bootstrapper that will - prior to executing the .msi - install all the pre-requisites.

Comment: Thanks. That would work if I was using the Visual Studion 2008 environment. But we are on 2005 and one of our ocx needs the CV++ Redistributable 9.0 to be registered. But we find a way. We add the merge module from 2008 in our setup and it works fine now. Thanks a lot for your help!